# Opening sms intent in Android lollipop

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm using the following code to open an intent.

The problem is that the sms_body is no shown in the intent

```
String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(numbers.toString())));
intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) 
{
    intent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
}
```

Any idea on how I can transfer the sms_body in lollipop.

Comment: where you start the `intent`? can you post full related code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
 String yournumber="123456";
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"+yournumber));
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "My first sms");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```